How to obtain the required height for an element, using the genpdf library?
Suppose I have a genpdf::Document. I use the push method to add new elements, such as paragraphs or tables to my PDF. I am aware that the library keeps track of the height of the rendered elements, so that a page break is added whenever needed. However, this feature doesn't work well with bordered tables (it breaks in an awful y position, keeping a small piece of vertical border spanning to the next page).
I would like to manually control the page breaks according to the remaining page height and the height required by each element I append to the page.
I didn't find anything suitable for this in the library documentation (so maybe this would be just a feature request). Is there any way to keep track of the y positions on the page or to know the size needed for an element before actually adding it to the document?
